# returning null value when flutter http get request(Instances of _<Future> dynamic)

Tags: flutter, api, flask, get, null

i am trying to get a data from a flask rest api but it keeps returning null value when it converted toString() it displays "Instances of _ dynamic"

```
getPass() async {
var response = await http.get(Uri.http("127.0.0.1:5000","generate"));
var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
var pass = jsonData['Password'];
return pass;
```

}

```
onPressed: () {
     getPassword = getPass().toString();
     setState(() {
     finalPassword = "hi $getPassword";
                    });
                  },
```

.....

```
Center(child: Text(
          finalPassword,
          //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'OpenSansCondensedBold',
            fontSize: 23,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        )),
```

api code

```
@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

def getPassword():  # put application's code here
global response
d={}

```
if request.method == "POST":

    input1 = request.form['Input1']
    input2 = request.form['Input2']
    input3 = request.form['Input3']
    response = Generation.GeneratePassword(input1, input2, input3)

    return " "
else:
    d['Password'] = response
    return jsonify(d)
```

displays out put when calling in browser but not in the app
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should await your call to getPass as it returns a future:

```
onPressed: () async {
     getPassword = await getPass();
     getPasswordString = getPassword.toString();
     setState(() {
     finalPassword = "hi $getPasswordString";
              });
          },
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: maybe you should call the await getPass(); in one line and then in the other you should say getPassword.toString();     I'll edit my answer